# How to go higher/lower in VIM and stay on the same column?

Tags: vim

How to go one line lower (or higher) and stay on the same column?

I need it for example to add a lot of aligned back-slashes when defining muli-line macros in C++, like in this:

```
#define MACRO(X)        \
     line1              \
                        \
     long long line3    \
     line4
```

If I will do `j` on line1 after adding `\`, cursor will jump to column 1 on line 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it myself:

```
set virtualedit=all
```

Answer (score 0):

Switching the `virtualedit` value every time might not be optimal. Setting it to `all` in vimrc might be crazy ;) I prefer to have `set virtualedit=block` in my vimrc, which is quite useful anyway. With it set, that edit can be done this way:

1. `f\` on the previous line to place cursor on `\`
2. `Ctrl-v` to enter visual block mode
3. `j` (or a couple of j's)
4. `r\` to replace selection with `\` (you could also use `c` to put more characters)